# unit test case for a asynchronous method ios

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, testing, asynchronous

i am new in the ios line. I have a task to crete test case for this method.

```
+ (void)myMethod:(NSString *)paramA callback:(void(^)(NSString *result, BOOL success))callback;
// ... Some code that runs async (for example, something that fetches data from the internet)...

// Call the callback function in a background thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    callback(@"Success", YES);
});
}
```

As through rnd i get to kno something related to `XCTestExpectation` used to create unit test cases....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `fulfill` in the compeletion block.  For example:

Assume the `FunctionObj` holds the function

```
@interface FunctionObj : NSObject
+ (void)myMethod:(NSString *)paramA callback:(void(^)(NSString *result, BOOL success))callback;
@end
@implementation FunctionObj
+ (void)myMethod:(NSString *)paramA callback:(void(^)(NSString *result, BOOL success))callback {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    callback(@"Success", YES);
    });
}
@end
```

Then the test case should be

```
- (void)testAsyncFunction {
    XCTestExpectation * expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Test async method"];
    [FunctionObj myMethod:@"1" callback:^(NSString *result, BOOL success) {
        XCTAssert(success,"should be succeed");
        XCTAssertNotNil(result,@"Should not be nil");
        [expectation fulfill];
    }];
    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10 handler:^(NSError *error) {
        //Do something when time out
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate... it serves my purpose....

just want to ask a thing like this is for testing purpose. so this singly test fulles every purpose means from every point of view like values change, data interrupted, time out etc....